# Why doesn't TTimer work correctly?

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-2010

As you can tell, I am having a little trouble with the TTimer VCL component within my application developed using Delphi 2010.

Whenever I call:

```
Self.Timer1.Enabled := False;
Self.Timer1.Enabled := True;
```

The timer component does seem to indeed halt, but, it never starts up again. Like, it never calls the OnTimer event.

I am using it in conjunction with the Indy10 IRC component (TIdIRC).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish setting Enabled to false then true in sequence. I don't have any problem using timers in Delphi. Please post a more complete example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Timer in a separate thread and everything is working well again :)

Thanks guys, I learned a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You are also aware that most Indy calls are blocking? A timer works by sending Windows Messages which means the messages need to be processed in order for the timer to fire. If the application/main thread blocks it does not process messages and timers do not get fired. Maybe this is your problem?

Also if your application is a Windows Service or a console application the messages might not be processed.

Comment: Basically, I'm making a quiz bot. After every X milliseconds (10000/10 seconds), it will give out a hint. If a user gets' the question correct, it will stop the timer (by the above method) and will go and give out the next question. Hope I made sense :/

Comment: How can I fix it if this is the case?

Comment: Use threads or don't use Indy. Don't use TTimer in a Windows Service or a console application.

Answer (score 2):

Take Indy out of the equation and see if you can get it to basically throw up the hint every 10 seconds. If not, you're doing something wrong. Like mis-interpreting the interval time.  For instance, "(10000/10 seconds)" is not very clear. I think you mean "10000ms which is 10 seconds" but you don't show your code, so I can only guess. Delphi won't guess, it will do what you tell it.
Anyway, make a sample app with a form, button, edit box and a ttimer and experiment. Get the timer stuff working, before you introduce the Indy stuff. Then you know whether you've got a TTimer problem or an Indy problem.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to mention that the Timer calls the OnTimer event every 10 seconds. It works when I don't modify the enabled state but until I do, it stops calling the OnTimer event :/

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that you call these methods of `TTimer` only in the context of the main thread. Since Indy uses threads it may well be the case that this rule is violated. To find out easily you can call `Assert` when the code is executed in the context of another thread:

```
Assert(GetCurrentThreadId = MainThreadId);
Self.Timer1.Enabled := False;
Self.Timer1.Enabled := True;
```

I don't know what `Self` is referring to in your code, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Self refers to the form class.